# PostgreSQL DB query with Fluent 4

Tags: swift, vapor, vapor-fluent

A Fluent Data query with the function below works:

```swift
func indexHandler(_ req: Request) -> EventLoopFuture<[CustomerWithOrders]> {
    Customer
        .query(on: req.db)
        .with(\.$orders)
        .all()
        .map { customers in
            customers.map { customer in
            let customerOrders = customer.orders.map {
                OrderOnly(id: $0.id, date: $0.date)
            }
            return CustomerWithOrders(
                id: customer.id, 
                name: customer.name, 
                orders: customerOrders
            )
        }             
    }
}
```

```swift
struct OrderOnly: Content {
    let id: UUID?
    let date: Date
}

struct CustomerWithOrders: Content {
    let id: UUID?
    let name: String
    let orders: [OrderOnly]
}
```

but not after the exchange: `[CustomerWithOrders]` to `View` in `EventLoopFuture`

```swift
func indexHandler(_ req: Request) -> EventLoopFuture<View> {
    Customer
        .query(on: req.db)
        .with(\.$orders)
        .all()
        .map { customers in //Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
            customers.map { customer in
                let customerOrders = customer.orders.map {
                    OrderOnly(id: $0.id, date: $0.date)
                }    
                let context = IndexContextcwo(
                    id: customer.id,
                    name: customer.name,
                    orders: customerOrders
                )    
                return req.leaf.render("home", context)
            }               
        }
}
```

```swift
struct IndexContextcwo: Encodable {
    let id: UUID?
    let name: String
    let orders: [OrderOnly]?
}
```

How can I get rid of the error `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" in the row ".all().map`?

Thanks for a tip.

Thank you for your answers.

With changing from map to flatmap I get no further. Now an error is:

Value of type 'EventLoopFuture<[Customer]>' has no member 'flatmap'

Here are some files from the project:

WebsiteController.swift:

```
import Vapor
import Leaf
import Fluent
import FluentPostgresDriver

struct WebSiteController: RouteCollection {
func boot(routes: RoutesBuilder) throws {
    routes.get(use: indexHandler)
}

func indexHandler(_ req: Request)
-> EventLoopFuture<View> {
    
    Customer.query(on: req.db).with(\.$orders)
        .all().map { customers in
         customers.map { customer in
         let customerOrders = customer.orders.map {
         OrderOnly(id: $0.id, date: $0.date)
         }                  
           let context = IndexContextcwo(id: customer.id, name: customer.name, orders: customerOrders)                
           return req.leaf.render("home", context)
    }
 }
    
    //Test without Custommer.query ...:
    //return req.leaf.render("home")
  }

}

struct OrderOnly: Content {
let id: UUID?
let date: Date
}

struct CustomerWithOrders: Content {
let id: UUID?
let name: String
let orders: [OrderOnly]
}

struct IndexContextcwo: Encodable {
let id: UUID?
let name: String
let orders: [OrderOnly]?
}
```

Models:

Customer.swift:

```
import Foundation
import Vapor
import Fluent
import FluentPostgresDriver

final class Customer: Model, Content {
static let schema = "customers"

@ID
var id: UUID?

@Field(key: "name")
var name: String

@Siblings(through: OrderCustomerPivot.self, from: \.$customer, to: \.$order)
var orders: [Order]

init() {}

init(id: UUID? = nil, name: String) {
self.id = id
self.name = name
 }
}
```

Order.swift:

```
import Foundation
import Vapor
import Fluent
import FluentPostgresDriver

final class Order: Model {
static let schema = "orders"

@ID
var id: UUID?

@Field(key: "date")
var date: Date

@Siblings(through: OrderCustomerPivot.self, from: \.$order, to: \.$customer)
var customers: [Customer]

init() {}

init(id: UUID? = nil, date: Date) {
self.id = id
self.date = date
 }
}

extension Order: Content {}
```

OrderCustomerPivot.swift

```
import Foundation
import Fluent

final class OrderCustomerPivot: Model {
static let schema = "order-customer-pivot"

@ID
var id: UUID?

@Parent(key: "orderID")
var order: Order

@Parent(key: "customerID")
var customer: Customer

init() {}

init(id: UUID? = nil, order: Order, customer: Customer) throws {
self.id = id
self.$order.id = try order.requireID()
self.$customer.id = try customer.requireID()
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If my answer helped you, please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get the error is because the `.map` means your code is expected to return a future of the same type, i.e. `[CustomerWithOrders]`. This is obviously correct in the first instance, but when you make the change to return the future `View` it isn't any longer.

From just inspecting your code, I think changing the first `.map` to `.flatMap` should fix the problem. This says you are going to return a different future, which is what you want.

Comment: This is correct. The second `map` is an Array `map` not a future map